# How to set fill style to no brush on QGIS using pyQgis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, polygon, symbology, style

I need set fill style "No Brush" but still stuck how to, here is my current code:

```
mySymbol1=QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple({'color':'#289e26',
                                                'color_border':'#289e26',
                                                'width_border':'1',
                                                'brushStyle':'No Brush'})
myRenderer = layer_base.rendererV2()
myRenderer.setSymbol(mySymbol1)
layer_base.triggerRepaint()
```

I am not sure and I think 'brushStyle:'No Brush' isn't the correct one, any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to replace `'brushStyle':'No Brush'` with `'style':'no'`:

```
layer_base = iface.activeLayer()
mySymbol1=QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple({'color':'#289e26',
                                                'color_border':'#289e26',
                                                'width_border':'1',
                                                'style':'no'})
myRenderer = layer_base.rendererV2()
myRenderer.setSymbol(mySymbol1)
layer_base.triggerRepaint()
```

---

Example:

[image: Result]